Angular 18, mat-select not working when used in custom contol
I tried to create custom control which contains the <mat-select> control. It is not working when I tied to use it in the Form control. I have taken the reference from the official Material website.
https://v18.material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control
https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fexample%2Fform-field-custom-control-example.ts
Used the same code and created a working example in Angular 18. In the example there are two custom controls added on the page 'Phone number' and 'Dropdown'.
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Phone number</mat-label>
        <example-tel-input formControlName="Phone1" required></example-tel-input>
        <mat-icon matSuffix>phone</mat-icon>
        <mat-hint>Include area code</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Phone number</mat-label>
        <app-my-phone formControlName="Phone2"></app-my-phone>
        <mat-icon matSuffix>phone</mat-icon>
        <mat-hint>Add number</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>My DD</mat-label>
        <app-my-dd formControlName="Gender"></app-my-dd>
        <mat-hint>Select dropdown</mat-hint>
    </mat-form-field>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <p>Entered value: {{form.valueChanges | async | json}}</p>
</div>

The first one for 'Phone number' ( formControlName="Phone1" ) is working fine and giving me the updated values. But the 'Dropdown' ( formControlName="Gender" ) control is not giving me the updated values.
Before adding inputs

After adding inputs

I tried to use the mat-select in the custom control. The cutom control contains the HTML code
<div
  role="group"
  [formGroup]="parts"
  [attr.aria-labelledby]="_formField?.getLabelId()"
  (focusin)="onFocusIn()"
  (focusout)="onFocusOut($event)">

    <mat-select
        formControlName="partsSelectedValue">
        <mat-option value="Male">Male</mat-option>
        <mat-option value="Female">Female</mat-option>
    </mat-select> 

</div>

The complete code is available on git hub. https://github.com/gurpreet42/AngularMaterialCustomContol
Please go through the code and suggest why custom control is not working when I used the Material Select control.

All those controls that are working fine because update value through calling this.onChange(...) but you don't do that
